# Ajax response always goes to success

Tags: php, ajax

I have a form where the user has to enter their reservation id and last name. If these two values match in the database then I need to return the corresponding values from the database.

It looks like even if the wrong reservation id and name are put in, it treats it as success. The page reloads and display the foobar.

Here is my code

test06.php

```
<?php

$conn = mysqli_connect("","","","");

$reservation_id=$_POST['reservation_id'];
$guest_last_name=$_POST['guest_last_name'];

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT reservation_id, guest_last_name, guest_full_name, unit_number, floor, key_sa 
                        FROM reservations2 
                            INNER JOIN guest ON (reservations2.reservation_id=guest.reservation_idg) 
                            INNER JOIN unit USING (unit_id) 
                        WHERE reservation_id=? 
                        AND guest_last_name=?");
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $reservation_id, $guest_last_name);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($reservation_id, $guest_last_name, 
                   $guest_full_name, $unit_number,  
                   $floor, $key_sa);
if ($stmt->errno) {
    die("Query failed to execute: " . $stmt->error);
}
if ($stmt->fetch()) {
    echo json_encode(array("reservation_id" => $reservation_id, 
                           "guest_last_name" => $guest_last_name,  
                           "guest_full_name" => $guest_full_name,  
                           "unit_number" => $unit_number,  
                           "floor" => $floor,  
                           "key_sa" => $key_sa));
} else {
    $error="Not matching record";
    echo json_encode($error);
}
$stmt->close();

?>
```

Inside HTML page

```
<p id='guest_full_name'></p>
<p id='unit_number'></p>
<p id='floor'></p>
<p id='error'></p>

<script>
function validateReservation(){
  var reservation_id = document.getElementById("reservation_id").value;
  var guest_last_name = document.getElementById("guest_last_name").value;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'test06.php',
        // dataType: 'json',
        data: {
                'reservation_id': reservation_id,
                'guest_last_name' : guest_last_name
            }, 
        success: function(json) {
            var json = JSON.parse(json);
            console.log(json);
            $('#guest_full_name').html(json.guest_full_name);
            $('#unit_number').html(json.unit_number);   
            $('#floor').html(json.floor);
            $('#key_sa').html(json.key_sa);
            }, 
        error: function(err) {
            console.log(err);
            $("#error").html("Error!");
            } 
    }); 
}
```

Comment: jquery `error` callback triggers when there's a server error, not when you send json with `error` field as repsonse.

Comment: Outputting "error" in the response doesn't make it an error that jquery recognizes as an error.

Comment: I find it easier just to include a `'success'=>true/false` in the json, and just look at that in the `success:` callback... instead of try to get it to fall into the `error:` callback. Because to me, "success" in ajax means all went well with the ajax call itself and now I should deal with the json accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to send the status code. Echoing JSON will just give you a 200 response.

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
http_response_code(500); 
echo $json;
exit;
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php